# How to find/grep all paths where directory name matches "x" but not "y" on *nix?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, find, grep

I have a folder structure like this (which is a small snippet):

```
└── test
    └── cases
        └── model
            ├── client
            │   ├── socketsTest.coffee
            ├── server
            │   └── socketsTest.coffee
            └── shared
                └── findersTest.coffee
```

The question is, how do you list all paths that end in `.coffee` and don't exist in the `client` folder?

The following command returns all files matching `.coffee` that exist in the `server` folder:

```
find test -name "*Test.coffee" | egrep '/*server*/'
```

But what I really need is a regex that matches everything **except** what's in the client folder.

What is the cleanest way to do this on *nix? The end goal is to return files not inside a `client` folder, so for the above tree that would be:

```
$ <find files except those a client folder>
test/cases/model/server/socketsTest.coffee
test/cases/model/shared/findersTest.coffee
```

I tried doing something like this but no luck:

```
find test -name "*Test.coffee" | egrep '*model/[^client]*'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `-prune` action to ignore directories. `-o` means "or", so read this as, "if it's named client prune it, otherwise print files named `*.coffee`".

```
find test -name client -prune -o -name '*.coffee' -print
```

Or you can use a double test, which is easier to read but slightly less efficient, since it'll recurse into `client/` directories, whereas the first one avoids them entirely.

```
find test -name '*.coffee' ! -wholename '*/client/*'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd second the `-prune` answer that John Kugelman gives.

Another way to solve this problem using `grep` is to use the `-v` option:

```
find test -name "*Test.coffee" | grep -v client
```

`-v` inverts the pattern match, so all the matches that contain "client" are discarded